# A crash I can fix, but I don't understand why it's happening

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a scrollview. I add a button to this scrollview and release it after.

```
UIButton * saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
saveButton.frame = CGRectMake(415.0, 473, 80, 38);
saveButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:24];
[saveButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[saveButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 0, 0, 0)];
saveButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[saveButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
[saveButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"save.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(save) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
saveButton.hidden = NO;
[self.scrollview addSubview:saveButton];
[saveButton release];
```

The application crashes when the view appears on screen, and I try and touch any part of the screen.

If I comment out

```
[saveButton release];
```

the application works perfectly.

I thought the retain count of the button would be incremented once I add it to the scrollview so it would be safe for me to release the button.

What's going on here? Is adding something to a scrollview not the same as adding it to the main view like below?

```
[self.view addSubview:saveButton];
```

Comment: `buttonWithType` is Class method, so it already creates an autoreleased instance, no need to release it. Check this developer.apple page for details - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Comment: i think save button has auto released reference and it cannot be released.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`buttonWithType:` is a convenience constructor, so it already creates an autoreleased instance, and there is no need to release the object.

That means the following line of code is an error:

```
[saveButton release];
```

You should not send `release`, as the instance is already autoreleased.

Check the [`UIButton` reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIButton * saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

This according to the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) this code returns an autoreleased object and you don't have to release it when you finish your job with it. When you add it as a subview of a view, the view you are adding it to is retaining it and you are not responsible for its memory management.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `alloc/init/new` used here , so this will be autoreleased. If you had something like this `UIButton *savebutton = [[UIButton alloc]init];` then you would have to use release like : `[saveButton release];`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]
```

method returns an autoreleased object which is only retained by the autorelease pool (which will release the object at the end of current event queue). That means that you have no ownership over it (it's not retained). Adding it to scroll view bumps the retain count by one, however you immediately destroy it in the next line by sending a release message.

The correct way to do this would be to remove the release call (and you'll be perfectly clear with memory management).

You can read more on iOS memory management [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: One can't know for sure what the retainCount will be at any specific instant, you can know that the object has been alloced, retained and autoreleased.

Comment: True, however that's just a simple example to show how the overall memory management process works. From "our" (aka developer) perspective the button at that point should only be retained by the autorelease pool that's handling the current event loop. (until you add it to the scrollView, that is).

Comment: An object's retain count can never be zero.

Comment: Indeed, when it reaches retain count 0 it's destroyed. But, again, for the purpose of explaining the "ownership" (maybe a better word for this example) saying that it's ownership is 0 when it's only retained by an autorelease pool seems fine.

Comment: But it isn't fine;  you are still speaking (a) in absolute terms of retain count and (b) implying that a retain count of 0 is possible.  There is no need to create new language around this;  "At this point, the object is autoreleased.  If you want to keep a reference to it beyond this scope, you must retain it." is the accepted vernacular and quite accurate.   Sure;  slightly pedantic, but the reality is that inventing new, ambiguous, concepts to describe already well described concepts helps no one.

Comment: I totally agree that inventing new concepts does not necessary help in understanding an issue, however the ownership concept is not something that I've invented. It's a concept from the memory management tutorial that is linked in several posts above and it did help me a lot to get a grasp on the ObjC memory management. And nowhere have I implied that retain count can be 0 (see the "Indeed, when it reaches retain count 0 it's destroyed").

Comment: You said "method returns an autorelease object with retainCount equal to 0" which pretty directly states that the retain count is 0 because of the autorelease. Out of curiosity, which tutorial?

Comment: bbum: True, I've edited the answer to correct the mistake. My bad. As for the tutorial, it's in the Apple Memory Management tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 0):

You hav'nt allocate memory to the button object. so how can you release it.

```
UIButton * saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

You called a static method which itself take care of memory management.
That is the only cause of app crashing.

Comment: The object and thus it's memory has been allocated, retained **and** autoreleased